# Change font name in Linux

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm using different fonts in XeLaTex. However, there are some fonts installed in the same name in my system. How can I change the name of the fonts to distinguish them in Linux System?

Comment: https://fontforge.github.io/fontinfo.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of changing the symbolic name you can access the fonts via the path. For example:

```
 \setmainfont
  [ Numbers = {T,LF},
    Extension  = .ttf,
    Path       = /usr/local/share/fonts/,
    UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
    ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
    BoldFont       = *-Bold , 
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
    UprightFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = AlegreyaSC-Regular },
    BoldFeatures = { SmallCapsFont= AlegreyaSC-Bold },
    ItalicFeatures = { SmallCapsFont= AlegreyaSC-Italic },
    BoldItalicFeatures = {  SmallCapsFont= AlegreyaSC-BoldItalic }]
  {Alegreya}
```